# How can I fix this error in DOM manipulation and error getting an HTML line to the console?

Tags: javascript, html, css, console.log

Whenever I print any text to the console that is being printed successfully. But when I try to print the HTML line to the console even with ID or class name. That is not working and giving me the output null.
I have this HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Number Game</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <main>
      <header>
        <h1>Guess the number between 1 and 100</h1>
        <button class="play-again">Play Again</button>
        <h2 class="result">Result</h2>
      </header>
      <hr />
      <section class="left-content">
        <input type="number" class="input-value" />
        <button class="check-result">Check</button>
      </section>
      <section class="right-content">
        <p class="message" id="message">Start guessing the number...</p>
        <p class="label-score">Score: <span class="score">20</span></p>
        <p class="label-highscore">
          Highscore: <span class="highscore">0</span>
        </p>
      </section>
    </main>
  </body>
</html>
```

The CSS code is:

```
* {
  font-family: Raleway, sans-serif;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

h1 {
  margin-top: 30px;
  font-size: 150%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}

.play-again {
  padding: 5px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  text-align: center;
  width: fit-content;
  display: block;
  border: none;
  background-color: rgb(38, 194, 64);
  border-radius: 3px;
}

.result {
  text-align: center;
}

.left-content {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
}

input {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding: 8px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: block;
}

.right-content {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
}

.check-result {
  padding: 5px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  display: block;
  background-color: rgb(38, 194, 64);
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: none;
}

.check-result:hover,
.play-again:hover {
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px black;
}
```

And the JavaScript code is:

```
"use strict";
console.log(document.querySelector("#message"));
console.log("hi");
```

The "hi" text printed successfully to the console, but the second line gives me "null" in Chrome. I have also reinstalled Chrome.

image link= "https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Iq2kHr6YFFAWl0pHLnpI9uiWY2WyBwno/view?usp=sharing"

Comment: You're running the script before the DOM has appeared. Place your script call just before the `</body>` tag so you allow the DOM to establish.

Comment: @Andy Your comment has solved my problem. You can post an answer. I will accept that.

Comment: The link is broken - *"Sorry, the file you have requested does not exist."*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Javascript code is running before the HTML finishes loading, to prevent this, add the `defer` attribute to your `<script>` tag as follows

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Number Game</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    
    <!-- Adding the defer attribute -->
    <script src="script.js" defer></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <main>
      <header>
        <h1>Guess the number between 1 and 100</h1>
        <button class="play-again">Play Again</button>
        <h2 class="result">Result</h2>
      </header>
      <hr />
      <section class="left-content">
        <input type="number" class="input-value" />
        <button class="check-result">Check</button>
      </section>
      <section class="right-content">
        <p class="message" id="message">Start guessing the number...</p>
        <p class="label-score">Score: <span class="score">20</span></p>
        <p class="label-highscore">
          Highscore: <span class="highscore">0</span>
        </p>
      </section>
    </main>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have added `<script>` tag in the head section that means your javascript load before the  `<p id="message">` tag which you want to get and log in console.

Solution - add you script file just before `</body>` tag closing.

Answer (score 0):

**You have to remove the -script- tag to the -head- and put it to the end of the -body-**

Comment: Praveen Kumar already said this